# Web application, minimize IE, takes a while to restore

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

I have a Web Application where the front end is Angular/Jquery.

I am experiencing some strange behaviour that I cannot reproduce in house, and have been troubleshooting for a while with no resolutions. I am wondering just if anyone has opinions of where to look next.

Basically we run our page inside of IE11. There is a combination of Kendo Grid, Jquery, and Angular running the front end.

Everything is fine normally, but if you minimize IE, and leave it minimized for a extended period of time (30-45 minutes), when you try to restore IE, it takes about 30-45s before it restores.

At first I thought it was some scripts failing, but leaving the debugger and console up shows everything appears to be continuing to running.

Then I thought maybe all my stuff was being paged off...so I disabled paging on the workstation.

Now I am thinking that maybe JQuery might be slow after inactivity? and causing some delay to bring the page back to life?

Any other ideas to look at?

Comment: We definitely need more info/code/example to get a clue about what you are doing.

Comment: Perhaps monitor iexplore.exe in Task Manager, to see what the memory/CPU usage is, and if it increases over time.  If it does, your code might have a memory leak of some kind.